# How to catch the kill signal inside c++ code

Tags: c++, out-of-memory, signals, kill

I am testing an algorithm which can use lots of memory. I am running the algorithm on a shared machine. As I am expecting my application sometimes is being killed by OOM killer, receiving the following text:

`Killed`

However, inside my code I have the possibility to suspends some threads and free some resources, in such situations. 
Is this possible that I handle the OS signal myself, and by freeing some resources prevent my application from being killed?

Comment: Maybe this helps http://www.tutorialspoint.com/cplusplus/cpp_signal_handling.htm

Comment: SIGKILL cannot be caught.